# Почему может не отрабатывать инструкция DELETE в которой условие WHERE имеет символ плюса?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица которое содержит поле типа VARCHAR с текстом `one+two` , при попытке его удалить запросом `DELETE FROM my WHERE test='one+two'` удаления не происходит, хотя база отвечает словами запрос выполнен успешно. Символ плюса убираешь из поля и запроса и этот запрос отрабатывает нормально. Проблема наблюдается только у хостера, на локальном тестовом сервере таких проблем нет...

С чем подобное может связано?

Comment: Можете расписать подробнее как выполняется запрос? В консоли, в каком-то клиенте, в вашей программе?

Comment: @cheops , вроде бы достаточно информации. в таблицу ложится запись инструкцией `$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO services (service, price) VALUES ('$_POST[service]', '$_POST[price]')");` удаляю `$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM services WHERE service=$_GET[del]");` если в поле `service` отправляется символы плюсов то удаления не происходит. а что нужно уточнить для полноты полной картины?

Comment: Странно, у вас параметр $_GET[del] не обернут кавычками в запросе "DELETE FROM services WHERE service=$_GET[del]", знак плюс будет интерпретироваться как + языка запроса SQL.

Comment: я так же подумал но все нормально он в самой ссылке обернут. в одинарные кавычки

Comment: @cheops ссылка выглядит следующим образом: ... service.php?del='one+two'

Comment: VALUES c кавычками вставляете, делайте так и в DELETE

Comment: @Jean-Claude , я этот вопрос подымал здесь но никто внятный ответ не дал, а в чем разница будет где кавычки ставить?

Comment: @perfect Не безопасно получается и с точки зрения проведения SQL-инъекций и надежности кода. Лучше явно задать кавычки в запросе, через параметр передавать только значение, причем обязательно его экранировать. Если у вас у хостера старый PHP, возможно там еще и магические кавычки включены, в этом случае ' может заменяться на \' автоматически и ваше выражение не срабатывает. Попробуйте еще дополнительно обработать ошибки - запрос нормально отрабатывает или возвращает сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: @cheops , пишит что запрос выполнен успешно и даже время выполнения показывает, а эффекта нет. наверно действительно что с настройками PHP или MYSQL. в общем то баг я пофиксил. просто интересно стало от чего это произошло.

Comment: @perfect, вы плюс отправляете в строке запроса `service.php?del='one+two'` и вероятно он у вас в пробел преобразовывается, в mysql уходит запись не `one+two`, а `one two`.

Comment: @Visman вполне вероятно.